# What are the benefits of using a computed static variable? - Swift

Tags: swift

What are the benefits of using a computed static var in Swift?

For example,

```
    static var now: Date {
        return Date()
    }
```

I am trying to figure out the benefits of static constants and static computed properties. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties are a tool. Every time you read from the property, your closure gets executed and the result is returned as the value of the property.

That can be useful for things that are easier to compute than to store (e.g. adding a maxX property to a rectangle struct if it didn't already have it.)

A static var belongs to the class/object type rather than an instance of that type. So a static computed property would be good for a value that's global to the type, changes, and is fast to compute.